# Why is there white space above my content on only one server?

Tags: css, html

I am working on a website with 4 servers with a load balancer. It is www.cleantelligent.com.

All of the seervers have an idtentical copy of the website on them. But on one of the servers, there is a white bar above the main content, below the header, that should not be there. I've tried re-copying all of the css and index files to the server, but it's still not working.

The server is called enos.
So, it's enos.cleantelligent.com

Can anyone tell me what's causing this stupid little white bar? It's not showing up as an individual element, but as part of the background content, I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the HTML of your page and there is this code just over your `<!-- #branding -->` comment. this is the white space you see :

```
<li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76"><a href="/cleantelligent-pricing">Plans &amp; Pricing</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-123"><a title="Login" href="/app/login.do">Login</a></li>
            <!-- #access -->
```

Also, it repeats the `<!-- #access -->` HTML comment twice. On the site without white space, there is only one "access" comment, but now there is two (go see in your page's html source code). I guess that in your script, you use a reference to the name of the server on a condition and it determines if it outputs or not this block of code. See back in your code where does this comes from and try to correct the condition.

Comment: Weird... You are right. I literally copied everything completely without changes... Well, oh well. It's fixed. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have two

elements on their own in the

<li id="menu-item-123" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-123"><a title="Login" href="/app/login.do">Login</a></li>

That's why you've got the white bar. Why those are there is something I can't really help you with ;)